# php hyperlink insert error

Tags: php, hyperlink

I am not able to insert hyperlink in php, the page goes blank when I insert the hyperlink in the way given below:

```
echo "' &bull; {$row['ntitle']}: <a href=\"detail.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '\" class=\"style1\">Detail </a>'";
```

Please help me out to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line contains errors related with the opening and close of quotes and double quotes.

This should do the work:

```
echo "&bull; {$row['ntitle']}: <a href=\"detail.php?id={$row['id']}\" class=\"style1\">Detail </a>";
```

That should output something like:

```
• yourTitle: Detail
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 echo "&bull; ".$row['ntitle']." : <a href=\"detail.php?id='" . $row['id'] . "'\" class=\"style1\">Detail </a>";
```

your line have error, use the following lines to show the proper errors on php on the start of page.

```
 ini_set('display_errors','1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

your string is not correct quotted

try this instead of yours:

```
echo ' &bull; '.$row["ntitle"].': <a href="detail.php?id=' . $row["id"] . '" class="style1">Detail </a>';
```

or use [printf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) for not being confused by lots of quotes and concats:

```
printf(' &bull; %s: <a href="detail.php?id=%s" class="style1">Detail </a>', $row["ntitle"], $row["id"]);
```

And definitely turn displaying errors/warnings/notices on http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php.

Answer (score 0):

Use sprintf function to format your string. Try this.

```
$string = sprintf(" &bull; %s: <a href=\"detail.php?id=%s\" class=\"style1\">Detail </a>",$row["ntitle"],$row["id"]);
echo $string;
```